# Botocore - how to handle failover condition

Tags: amazon-s3, boto, boto3, botocore

I have more than 4 servers up and running s3-auth server on them.
I am able to authenticate user from first server.

if we turn off first server, how to validate that s3 server is not running on first server through botocore, so it should automatically use next server.

When i turn off first server and send request to list users, response never comes from botocore. It retry operation for 5 times and after that it do nothing.

Botocore Version: 1.3.30
Boto3 version: 1.2.2

Please help on this.
See below botocore logs:

```
DEBUG:botocore.endpoint:Response received to retry, sleeping for 7.72060814652 seconds
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event request-created.iam.ListUsers: calling handler <bound method RequestSigner.handler of <botocore.signers.RequestSigner object at 0x7f238444ccd0>>
DEBUG:botocore.auth:Calculating signature using v4 auth.
DEBUG:botocore.auth:CanonicalRequest:
POST
/

host:iam.test.com:8085
user-agent:Boto3/1.2.2 Python/2.7.5 Linux/3.10.0-229.11.1.el7.x86_64 Botocore/1.3.30
x-amz-date:20170322T131218Z

host;user-agent;x-amz-date
b6359072c78d70ebee1e81adcbab4f01bf2c23245fa365ef83fe8f1f955085e2
DEBUG:botocore.auth:StringToSign:
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20170322T131218Z
20170322/us-east-1/iam/aws4_request
e74bb593aaf7d92c8dfb517a4daedfe353ec4f9806a7b1c50bca7d7ed2e9e45e
DEBUG:botocore.auth:Signature:
adc96eb87a11f5b69214163bfafab7a82574113be0bcb0cddb43dfa70cbbc789
DEBUG:botocore.endpoint:Sending http request: <PreparedRequest [POST]>
INFO:botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (5): iam.test.com
DEBUG:botocore.endpoint:ConnectionError received when sending HTTP request.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 174, in _get_response
    proxies=self.proxies, timeout=self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/adapters.py", line 415, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(111, 'Connection refused'))
DEBUG:botocore.hooks:Event needs-retry.iam.ListUsers: calling handler <botocore.retryhandler.RetryHandler object at 0x7f23843a2790>
```

Comment: This isn't something botocore can handle. You'll need to have a load balancer route traffic appropriately.

Comment: Since you mentioned there is 4 server doing the same task, then you should check out how you setup the switch-over.   There must be mechanism build in front to do this switch-over, not botocore.  Without the mechanism, swith over will not happens. Do inspect the setup and give more details.